# Probability Question with a Dartboard and Darts with diameter 18 in and bullseye 2 in from center

Tags: probability, probability-theory, solution-verification

Suppose a circular dart board is $18$ inches in diameter, and the
bull’s eye in the center is $2$ inches in diameter. What is the probability that out of
four darts thrown at the dart board, exactly two hit the bull’s eye? Assume that
each dart lands at a uniformly random point on the board, independently of the
other darts.

I am just wondering if my method was correct, I found that the total area was $81\pi$ and the area of the center was $4\pi$, then I divide $\frac{4\pi}{81\pi}$ and then squared it to get $.0024$. Is that correct? and if it is not, Can you show where I went wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: Where does this take into account the fact that it was "*four darts thrown at the board*"?  Would you have thought it were the same answer if it were a million darts thrown at the board?

Comment: Look at the Binomial Distribution.

Comment: As another critique, you may want to recheck your geometry.  In particular, pay attention to the difference between a diameter and a radius.  Your calculations are inconsistent, having gone with $9^2\pi$ but having gone with $2^2\pi$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your process started out correct: The area of the board is

$$A_b=\pi r^2=81\pi$$

but the area of the bulls-eye is

$$A_e=\pi r^2=\pi$$

So the probability that any dart hits the bulls-eye is

$$P=\frac{A_e}{A_b}=\frac{\pi}{81\pi}=\frac{1}{81}$$

Now, to find the probability that exactly two darts hits the bulls-eye, first note there are exactly $\binom{4}{2}$ (read $4$ choose $2$) ways to choose exactly two darts from the four. This is defined as

$$\binom{4}{2}=\frac{4!}{2!(4-2)!}=\frac{24}{2\cdot 2}=6$$

Second, the probability that exactly two darts (in any order) hit the center is given by

$$P\cdot P\cdot (1-P)\cdot (1-P)=\frac{6400}{43046721}$$

Since there six ways to find arrange the darts and have this happen, the final probability of exactly two darts hitting the bulls-eye is given by

$$6\frac{6400}{43046721}=\frac{12800}{14348907}=0.0892054\%$$